# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>>' () to 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>' ()

Tags: ios, json, swift, post, nsdictionary

This is my JSON, when i read ord , uniq data i'm getting errors

```
let response2 : [String: Any]  = ["Response":["status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"SUCCESS","Array":[
                                ["ord":"50","uniq":"5a66c2348",
                                   "name":"SHREE","no":"UP11AT0","loc":"Hathin","lat":"23.33","lon":"87.09","date":"30-01-2018","time":"12:35:33","dis_dt":"00-00-0000","dis_tm":"00:00:00"],
                                ["ord":"50","uniq":"5a66c2348",
                                   "name":"SHREE","no":"UP11AT0","loc":"Hathin","lat":"23.33","lon":"87.09","date":"30-01-2018","time":"12:35:33","dis_dt":"00-00-0000","dis_tm":"00:00:00"],
                                ["ord":"50","uniq":"5a66c2348",
                                   "name":"SHREE","no":"UP11AT0","loc":"Hathin","lat":"23.33","lon":"87.09","date":"30-01-2018","time":"12:35:33","dis_dt":"00-00-0000","dis_tm":"00:00:00"]
                            ]],"count":"35"]
```

My code is

```
let status = "\((response2["Response"]! as! [String: Any])["status"]!)"
print(status)

if status == "SUCCESS" {
   let count = ((response2["Response"]! as! [String: Any])["Array"] as AnyObject).count!
   print(count)
   let ar = (response2["Response"]! as! [String: Any])["Array"]!
   print(ar)

   var ord_id: [Any] = []
   for i in 0..<count {
       ord_id.append((response2["Response"]! as! [String: Any])["Array"]! [0] as! [String:Any])// Here I'm getting Type 'Any' has no subscript members and 
   }

} else {
   print("Show alert")
}
```

When  write like this I'm getting Error: ***Type 'Any' has no subscript members***

```
let ar = (response2["Response"]! as! [String: Any])["Array"]! [0] as! [String: Any]
```

When I write like this Error: ***Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array>' (0x10bf341f0) to 'Swift.Dictionary' (0x10bf340d0).***

```
let ar = (response2["Response"]! as! [String: Any])["Array"]! as! [String: Any]
```

I'm unable to understand what is the exact problem an how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get count you need to do...

```
if let res = response2["Response"] as? [String: Any], let arr = res["Array"] as? [[String: Any]] {
  print("array count = \(arr.count)")
} else {
   print("Array not found !!")
}
```

To get array from "Response" key...

```
var ord_id: [Any] = []

if let res = response2["Response"] as? [String: Any] {
    if let arr = res["Array"] as? [Any], arr.count > 0 {
      print(arr)
      ord_id = arr
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

To get "old" and "uniq" key value, you need to get through an array and get required object.

```
var ordId_arr = [String]()
var uniq_arr = [String]()

for obj in ord_id {

 print(obj)

 if let dict = obj as? [String: Any] {
    //print(dict["ord"] as! String)
    //print(dict["uniq"] as! String)
    //print(dict["name"] as! String)
   //you can get other values in same way

   if let ord = dict["ord"] as? String {
        ordId_arr.append(ord)
    }

    if let uniq = dict["uniq"] as? String {
        uniq_arr.append(uniq)
    }
 }

}

print("\(ordId_arr)")
print("\(uniq_arr)")
```

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: It's printing empty arrays [ ]
[ ]

Comment: ok, Thank you very much I will try once again, And can you post some links hoe to read objects from JSON

Answer (score 1):

Parse can be done by, Also you can use `Decodable` for parsing JSON into objects.

```
let response = response2["Response"]! as! [String: Any]
let status = response["status"]!

if let array = response["Array"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
     print(array.count)   
     let ordArray = array.map { $0["ord"] }
     let unique = Array(Set(ordArray)) //Do if needs to stripe duplicates
     let uniqArray = array.map { $0["uniq"] }
     print(ordArray)
     print(uniqArray)
}
```

Comment: thank you, how to read "ord", and "uniq" objects. Can you please explain...
I want to save ord and uniq in arrays

Comment: you can use my code if you need minimized code. You can use [array.map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2963470-map). My code updated